# Ubuntu 14.04 Bluetooth will not Enable

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth

I just recently installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo Yoga as a dual boot. But due to unfortunate circumstances, my audio jack doesn't work. I usually use bluetooth, but whenever I try to enable bluetooth and close the window, it just resets itself back to disable. Any advice on how to deal with this situation?

Here is what displays:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:029c Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2047:0855 Texas Instruments 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:000a Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card  
Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

bluetooth             446409  12 bnep,rtk_btusb,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth

Linux Stephen-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Yoga-13 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Can you give some more information about your bluetooth device? Does `hcitool dev` - command for listing bluetooth devices - list anything?

Comment: It doesn't list anything, it just says "Devices: "

Comment: Can you edit question to add results from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; lsmod | grep bluetooth; uname -a; rfkill list all`

Comment: You likely need the wifi package from [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) and the bluetooth from [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt/tree/troy)

Comment: What are the commands, I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. I have Git Bash though, so I can use git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install

cd ~
git clone -b troy https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt.git
cd rtl8723au_bt
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and test, we may have to blacklist the rtk_btusb

Comment: Please do not recommend to install linux-headers-generic. It was needed only for 12.10 due to a bug. It can confuse things in LTS releases, which may have other headers, like linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic.

Comment: Same thing happens. It still doesn't work :/

Comment: Is the rtk_btusb module still getting loaded?  Check `lsmod | grep rtk_btusb`

Comment: I see this:

rtk_btusb              22985  0 
bluetooth             446409  12 bnep,rtk_btusb,rfcomm

Comment: Does `sudo modprobe -r rtk_btusb` followed by `sudo modprobe btusb` work ?

Comment: Now the command for lsmod | grep rtk_btusb doesn't show up with anything, but the bluetooth still won't enable.

Comment: does `lsmod | grep bluetooth` show btusb?

Comment: I wonder if you got a kernel update, you could try `cd rtlwifi_new; make clean && make && sudo make install` then `cd ~/rtl8723au_bt; make clean && make && sudo make install` then reboot